# Swift 2, UiCollectionview after scrolling - changed cells data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

For cells I just put info from array:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesCollectionViewCell

            if cell.dateLabel.text == "" {
                cell.dateLabel.text = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].datesStr
                cell.image.image = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].images
            }
            return cell
        }
```

To array, I generate data in DidAppear. Only one time. 
But When I scrolling collectionView - cells change data, for example:

1 cell - PictureA

2 cell - PictureB

then scrolling, and in collectionview will see:

1 cell - PictureB

2 cell - PictureA

then scrolling, and in collectionview will see again:

1 cell - PictureA

2 cell - PictureB

Can't understand what happen here...

Comment: add else condition too in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: try this `if cell.dateLabel.text == "" { cell.dateLabel.hidden = false cell.image.hidden = false cell.dateLabel.text = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].datesStr cell.image.image = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].images } else { cell.dateLabel.hidden = true cell.image.hidden = true } `

Comment: I add. And after scrolling all cells is empty....

Comment: @VladyslavPG Remove your check like this                                                      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesCollectionViewCell

           
                cell.dateLabel.text = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].datesStr
                cell.image.image = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].images
            
            return cell

Answer (score 1):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

      cell.dateLabel.text = nil
        cell.image.image = nil
```

}

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: This is actually weird, but this helps me in my problem. The idea is to reset the values here, and it works. Lol. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is table view `dequeue` your cell for optimization so you last cell dequeue. 
you should complete your code like this :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesCollectionViewCell

        if cell.dateLabel.text == "" {
            cell.dateLabel.text = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].datesStr
            cell.image.image = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].images
        }
          else { 
                cell.dateLabel.text = "" ( (or another string)
                cell.image.image = nil(or another image)

            }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 sry :)

Comment: Yes, I try it before, but if I add cell.image.image = nil - after scrolling I see just empty cells. After scrolling again - I see pictures again...

Comment: your statement isn't okay!
 ---------->  if cell.dateLabel.text == "" 
plz change your condition

Comment: I add this code: 
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesCollectionViewCell
        if cell.dateLabel.text == "" {
            cell.dateLabel.text = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].datesStr
            cell.image.image = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].images
        }
        else {
            cell.dateLabel.text = ""
                cell.image.image = nil  }
        return cell }

Answer (score 0):

Remove your check. Since cells are reused. You need to set the data every time

```
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImagesCollectionViewCell


 cell.dateLabel.text = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].datesStr
 cell.image.image = imagesDatas[indexPath.row].images

 return cell
```

Comment: Yes. This work. When I start to make collection view, i did like that. But now I need to set -  if dateLabel.text == "" { dateLabel.alpha = 1}

Comment: I mean, this code like you give - I use before. It is correct but not enough. I need to hide label if inside = "" . Can you help please ?

Comment: I am setting data every time, but still it is happening @Zartha